# Why Android studio spoiled my code when I opened my project again?

Tags: android

I am using android studio since last 6 months. Everything is fine with this IDE except, it spoils my code when I open my project again. This problem is not happening frequently. In these 6 months, android studio did that up to 10 times.

Below is an example of spoiled code of my @String directory but this problem also sometime occurs with other directories as well.

> ����   4� com/user/example/R$id  java/lang/Object
> com/user/example/R  id ALT I      BOTTOM_END
> BOTTOM_START    C